# If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open when $U$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open when $U$ is open.

**My attempts**

Let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. I have to show that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $]x-\delta,x+\delta[\subset f^{-1}(U)$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ small enough to have $]f(x)-\varepsilon,f(x)+\varepsilon[\subset U$. Since it's continuous at $x$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $y\in ]x-\delta,x+\delta[$ we have $$f(x)-\varepsilon<f(y)<f(x)+\varepsilon.$$
In particular, since $]f(x)-\varepsilon,f(x)+\varepsilon[\subset U$ then $f(y)\in f(U)$, and thus $y\in f^{-1}(U)$. Therefore $]x-\delta,x+\delta[\subset f^{-1}(U)$.

Therefore $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. Is it correct ?

Comment: The answer seems correct, actually it is: "...then $f(y)\in \color{red}{U}$, and thus $y\in f^{-1}(U)$."

Answer (score 1):

Besides a typo at the end, $f(y)\in U$ and not $f(y)\in f(U)$, the proof is correct.

Note that "$U$ open $\implies$ $f^{-1}(U)$ open" is a very important property of continuous functions.

Based on this characterization, the notion of continuity can be generalized for [functions between topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces).

For a proof that "$U$ open $\implies$ $f^{-1}(U)$ open" implies the $\epsilon\delta$-continuity of $f$ you can proceed as follow: Let $a\in \Bbb R$ and $U=]f(a)-\epsilon,f(a)+\epsilon[$. Then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. Since $a \in f^{-1}(U)$, there exists $\delta>0$ with $]a-\delta,a+\delta[\subset f^{-1}(U)$. It follows that $f(]a-\delta,a+\delta[)\subset U$ and thus, for every $b$ with $|a-b|<\delta$, we have
$|f(a)-f(b)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your complement, I really appreciate.